# How do I install mplayer from a terminal?

Tags: linux, install, suse, mplayer

I need a command to run on Linux to install mplayer. I'm not finding the command anywhere, and when I try to use the `zypper` command to install mplayer it tells me I am not a sudoer. What should I do?

Comment: We need some more information. What distribution are you using (openSUSE, I'm guesing)? Can you show the exact commands you gave and the exact error messages you got? Is this your own system? Do you expect to have `sudo` rights for administrative access?

Comment: MPlayer is one package I like to install from source. It's a little harder than `./configure && make && make install` but some distros ship really useless versions. And you don't need root for that just use `--prefix=${HOME}/mplayer`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should read `man sudoers` to know what you will be doing.

With that understanding, log in as root (can be done via `su -` command) and run **`visudo`**.

**You will be editing a security-critical system file, so make sure you understand the consequences.**
My suggestion on a sane contents of that file is to have

> Defaults log_output,rootpw

and

> %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL

Then logout and you should be able to run the command you wanted, supplying the root password when asked.